# How to filter out dot and dot dot(default unix inodes) while polling a directory using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, unix, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to use spring integration to poll some of my directories. Since spring integration writes in KeyValue table and it picks up this . as well as .. unix inode and tries to write repeatedly to my db table it throws exception after a few seconds of trying. I would like to learn a way to ignore them for spring to pickup. I am already using AcceptOnceFileListFilter. Also I have tried with a custom filter that filters out any file with filename length less than 3 but they are not working.

Update:

I am using `IgnoreHi‌​ddenFileListFilter` yet its not working.  I have narrowed the issue that Since my custom filter implements `FileListFilter < File >` all the files coming to this filter are java.io.File objects and it does not recognize `.` and `..` as Files. I confirmed this since my sftp remote filter implements `FileListFilter< LsEntry >` and it is correctly filtering out `.` and `..` which i can see in logs. However i cannot use `LsEntry` in local as it throws a type cast exception.

Here is my configuration for filters:

```
<bean id="remoteCompositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
<constructor-arg>
  <list>
    <bean class="com.file.RemoteCustomFilter"/>
  <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />
    <!-- download files whose extension is not .writing -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter" >
      <constructor-arg value="^.*(?&lt;!.writing)$" /> 
    </bean>
    <!-- List of qualifying files to be retrieved from remote server are stored in KEY_VALUE_STORE table.
         jdbcMetadataStore is defined in test-sftp-common.xml -->
    <bean id="remotePersistentFilter" 
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="store" ref="jdbcMetadataStore"/>
        <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
    </bean>
  </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

```
<bean id="localCompositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
<constructor-arg>
  <list>
    <bean class="com.file.CustomFilter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter" />

    <!-- download files whose extension is not .writing -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter" >
        <constructor-arg value="^.*(?&lt;!.writing)$" /> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="localIncomingPersistentFilter"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="store" ref="propertiesMetadataStore"/>
        <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true" />
    </bean>
  </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

And here is the CustomFilter

```
public class CustomFilter implements FileListFilter<File> {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomFilter.class); 
@Override
public List<File> filterFiles(File[] files) {
    List<File> filteredFileList = new LinkedList<File>();
    for (File this_file : files){
        log.info("Checking file : " + this_file.getAbsolutePath());
        if(!this_file.getName().startsWith(".")){
            filteredFileList.add(this_file);
            log.info("Adding local file to filtered list : " + this_file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else{
            log.info("Rejecting local file from filtered list : " + this_file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    return filteredFileList;
}
```

}

RemoteCustomFilter

```
public class RemoteCustomFilter implements FileListFilter<LsEntry> {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomFilter.class); 
@Override
public List<LsEntry> filterFiles(LsEntry[] files) {
    List<LsEntry> filteredFileList = new LinkedList<LsEntry>();
    for (LsEntry this_file : files){
        log.info("Checking file : " + this_file.getFilename());
        if(!this_file.getFilename().startsWith(".")){
            filteredFileList.add(this_file);
            log.info("Adding remote file to filtered list : " + this_file.getFilename());
        }
        else{
            log.info("Rejecting remote file from filtered list : " + this_file.getFilename());
        }
    }
    return filteredFileList;
}
```

}

This is what my DEBUG log looks like:

```
2017-02-02|13:26:17.878 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [doGetItem:190] - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3221346d.
2017-02-02|13:26:18.423 INFO  [task-scheduler-1] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:16] - Checking file : /outgoing/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:18.423 INFO  [task-scheduler-1] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:22] - Rejecting local file from filtered list : /outgoing/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:18.424 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:261] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.021 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [doGetItem:190] - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3b560425.
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-7] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-9] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-10] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-6] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-2] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-7] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-9] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.095 DEBUG [task-scheduler-10] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:208] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:19.372 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:17] - Checking file : .
2017-02-02|13:26:19.372 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:23] - Rejecting remote file from filtered list : .
2017-02-02|13:26:19.372 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:17] - Checking file : ..
2017-02-02|13:26:19.372 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:23] - Rejecting remote file from filtered list : ..
2017-02-02|13:26:19.854 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory [close:187] - Releasing Session org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3221346d back to the pool.
2017-02-02|13:26:19.854 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [releaseItem:221] - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3221346d back to the pool
2017-02-02|13:26:19.854 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer [synchronizeToLocalDirectory:270] - 0 files transferred
2017-02-02|13:26:19.854 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:16] - Checking file : incoming/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:19.855 INFO  [task-scheduler-3] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:22] - Rejecting local file from filtered list : incoming/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:19.855 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [doPoll:261] - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'
2017-02-02|13:26:21.080 INFO  [task-scheduler-1] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:16] - Checking file : incoming/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:21.080 INFO  [task-scheduler-1] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:22] - Rejecting local file from filtered list : incoming/.DS_Store
2017-02-02|13:26:21.081 DEBUG [task-scheduler-1] org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [doGetItem:185] - Obtained org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3221346d from pool.
2017-02-02|13:26:21.101 INFO  [task-scheduler-4] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:17] - Checking file : .
2017-02-02|13:26:21.102 INFO  [task-scheduler-4] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:23] - Rejecting remote file from filtered list : .
2017-02-02|13:26:21.102 INFO  [task-scheduler-4] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:17] - Checking file : ..
2017-02-02|13:26:21.102 INFO  [task-scheduler-4] com.file.CustomFilter [filterFiles:23] - Rejecting remote file from filtered list : ..
2017-02-02|13:26:21.707 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory [close:187] - Releasing Session org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3b560425 back to the pool.
2017-02-02|13:26:21.707 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [releaseItem:221] - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@3b560425 back to the pool
2017-02-02|13:26:21.707 DEBUG [task-scheduler-4] org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer [synchronizeToLocalDirectory:270] - 0 files transferred
```

But here is my KeyValue Table
[View of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doKpg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.7.RELEASE/api/index.html?org/springframework/integration/file/filters/IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter.html)

or a regex filter with `[^.].*`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using it yet its not working.
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter" />
I have narrowed the issue that Since my custom filter implements FileListFilter<File> all the files coming to this filter are java.io.File objects and it doesnot recognize . and .. as Files. I confirmed this since my sftp remote filter implements FileListFilter<LsEntry> and it is correctly filtering out . and .. which i can see in logs. However i cannot use LsEntry in local as it throws a type cast exception.

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments - as you can see it's unreadable - edit your question instead and then I'll take a look.

Comment: If you are trying to filter the remote `.` and `..`, use the `SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter`. However, that should not be necessary - we only fetch files and they are directories. It must be the local `.` an `..` you are picking up. You need to put the hidden file list filter in the `localFilter` not the `filter`.

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense to me. The synchronizer ignores remote directories; you will see `this.logger.debug("cannot copy, not a file: " + remoteFilePath);` messages under DEBUG logging. The local filter needs to be configured to ignore anything you don't want emitted as a message; the ignore hidden filter will do do that for `.` and `..`. You say you have a custom local filter; it should be combined with an ignore hidden filter in a `CompositeFileListFilter`. If you still can't figure it out; you need to show your complete configuration and a DEBUG log.

Comment: Thanks for responding so swiftly. I have added the configuration, the DEBUG log as well as a screenshot of my db table.

Comment: I don't see any messages being emitted; just "Received no message during poll". I think you might be misunderstanding how the `CompositeFileListFilter` works - the filters in the `CompositeFileListFilter` get to see all the files, but only those that pass __all__ the filters are actually released by the composite filter. We recently added the `ChainFileListFilter` (see [INT-4215](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4215)) where downstream filters only get to see those files passed by the previous filter.

Comment: That may be because I havent added any file in the polling directory to be picked up. That part is working fine. My concern is that I dont want .  and .. in the KeyValue table.

Comment: What i have understood from the log is that since the RemoteCustomFilter is using LsEntry its working as expected. LsEntry recognizes . and .. when passing the list of files to the filter. However at CustomFilter I am forced to use Java.io.file and since java.io.file object doesnot recognize . and .. they are not being passed to the filter to be taken out.

Comment: We seem to be talking past each other - even if the remote filter passes those files, they are ignored because the synchronizer doesn't copy directories. I don't understand what you mean by "not passed to the filter to be taken out". If they're not passed to the filter, then they can't ever be emitted as message payloads. `new File(".").listFiles()` does not include `.` and `..` (at least on OS X) so I don't know where they are coming from.

Comment: As per my understanding . and .. are not dirs  but inodes to current and parent dir respectively. I am convinced that these files are not coming down from the remote sftp location. these are present by default in every directory and in our case the local directory which is also being polled for moving files  locally . For my local filter  we are passing the list of files to the filter as java.io.file objects these would not be present in the list to begin with and as such filter would never encounter these to filter it out.But these files are picked up by spring to be written in the db table.

Comment: Java.io.File doesnot recognize . and .. and hence we will never find them in File(".").listFiles()

Comment: Well java understands `.` - `new File(".").listFiles()` lists all the files in the current directory (but it doesn't include `.` and `..`) and `new File(".").isDirectory()` returns `true` (and for `..` too). As I said, since the `DefaultDirectoryScanner` uses `listFiles`, I don't understand how `.` and `..` can be passed into your filter in the first place.